# BST in array traversal

Tags: c++, c, arrays, binary-search-tree

I have the following implementation of a binary tree in an array;

```
   32
  /  \
 2    -5
     /  \
   -331   399
```

The data is grouped 3 indexes at a time.  `index%3==0` is the value of the node, `index%3==1` is the index of the value of the left node and `index%3==2` is the index of the value of the right node.  If the left or right index reference is 0, there is no node that direction.

I'm trying to find the depth (height) of this tree.  I've written it recursively

```
height(node): 
   if node == null:
        return 0
   else:
        return max(height(node.L), height(node.R)) + 1
```

I want to find a non-recursive solution, however.

Here is some pseudocode i have, assuming the **tree is not empty**

```
int i = 0; int left = 0; int right = 0;
while (i != n ){
if ( a[i+1] != 0 ){
  left++;
}
else if ( a[i+2] != 0 ){
  right++;
}
 i = i + 3;
 }

return max ( left, right ) + 1;
```

I don't think this is right and I'd like some help figuring out how to do this correctly.

Comment: I'm editing this question...

Comment: that is not a BST at all

Comment: I've edited the question to be "binary tree" instead.  The question is  the same either way and it was easier than correcting the data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what your problem is with recursion for us to understand what behavior you want to improve.

There are many solutions to this, but almost all of them have the same or worse performance than your recursive solution.  Really, the best solutions are going to be things you'd have to do when you're creating the tree.  For example, you could store the height of each node in a fourth array index per node.  Then it's a trivial scan of every fourth index to find the max height.  It would also make it easier if nodes had parent references stored with them so that didn't have to be computed during the height check.

One solution is to simulate recursion with a stack, but that's really no different than recursion.

Another solution is to go through each node and determine its height based on it's parent, but not in a specific traversal's order.  However, because of how you have this configured, without a secondary datastructure to store the hierarchy, it's going to be less efficient O(n^2).  The problem is you can't get from the child to its parent without a full array scan.  Then you can do it in linear time (but recursion is also linear time, so I'm not sure we're doing better.  It's also not going to be much better from a memory perspective).

Can you define what type of efficiency you want to improve?

Here's the ***pseudocode*** for each, but I'm depending on a few datastructures that aren't easily present:

"recursion without recursion" solution:

```
int get_height(int * tree, int length) {

    Stack stack;

    int max_height = 0;

    if (length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // push an "array" of the node index to process and the height of its parent.  
    //   make this a struct and use that for real c code
    stack.push(0,0);

    while(!stack.empty()) {
        int node_index, parent_height = stack.pop();

        int height = parent_height + 1;
        if (height > max_height) {
            max_height=height;
        }
        if (tree[node_index+1] != 0 )
            stack.push(tree[node_index+1], height);
        if (tree[node_index+2] != 0 )
            stack.push(tree[node_index+2], height);

    }

    return max_height;
}
```

Now working on really slow solution that uses no additional memory, but it's REALLY bad.  It's like writing fibonacci recursively bad.  The original algorithm went through each node and performed O(n) checks worst case for a runtime of O(n^2) (actually not quite as bad as I had originally thought)

edit: much later I'm adding an optimization that skips all nodes with children.  This is REALLY important, as it cuts out a lot of calls.  Best case is if the tree is actually a linked list, in which case it runs in O(n) time.  Worst case is a fully balanced tree - with logn leaf nodes each doing logn checks back to the root for O((log(n)^2).  Which isn't nearly so bad.   Lines below to be marked as such

"really slow but no extra memory" solution (but now updated to not be nearly so slow):

```
int get_height(int * tree, int length) {
    int max_height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i+=3) {

        // Optimization I added later
        // if the node has children, it can't be the tallest node, so don't
        //   bother checking from here, as the child will be checked
        if (tree[i+1] != 0 || tree[i+2] != 0)
            continue;

        int height = 0;
        int index_pointing_at_me;

        // while we haven't gotten back to the head of the tree, keep working up
        while (index_pointing_at_me != 0) {
            height += 1; 
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j+=3) {
                if (tree[j+1] == tree[i] ||
                    tree[j+2] == tree[i]) {
                    index_pointing_at_me = j;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        if (height > max_height) {
            max_height = height;
        }

    }

    return max_height;
}
```

Improved on previous solution, but uses O(n) memory - this assumes parents are always before children in array (which I suppose isn't technically required)

```
int get_height(int * tree, int length) {

    if (length == 0) 
        return 0;

    // two more nodes per node - one for which node is its parent, the other for its height
    int * reverse_mapping = malloc((sizeof(int) * length / 3) * 2) 
    reverse_mapping[1] = 1; // set height to 1 for first node



    // make a mapping from each node to the node that points TO it.
    // for example, for the first node
    //    a[0] = 32
    //    a[1] = 3
    //    a[2] = 6
    //  store that the node at 3 and 6 are both pointed to by node 0 (divide by 3 just saves space since only one value is needed) and that each child node is one taller than its parent
    int max_height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i+=3) {

        int current_height = reverse_mapping[(i/3)*2+1];
        if (current_height > max_height)
            max_height = current_height;

        reverse_mapping[(tree[i+1]/3)*2] = i;
        reverse_mapping[(tree[i+1]/3)*2 + 1] = current_height + 1;

        reverse_mapping[(tree[i+2]/3)*2] = i;
        reverse_mapping[(tree[i+2]/3)*2 + 1] = current_height + 1;

    }
    return max_height
}
```

Comment: is there a reason reverse_mapping[(tree[i+2]/3)*2] = i;
reverse_mapping[(tree[i+2]/3)*2 + 1] = current_height + 1; is added twice?

Comment: also shouldn't we check if tree[i+1] == 0 ... if it does it causes reverse_mapping to go back to indicie [0] and [1]

Comment: I don't think I set it twice.  One is i+1 the other is i+2.  As for checking if it is 0, you could but I thought about it and I don't think it matters, but I could be wrong.  You set the value, but you would never use it, so it shouldn't matter.  But there are likely some bugs in the code I wrote.

Comment: Ahh i didnt see that +2 ... it works like a charm, thanks a bunch xaxxon

Comment: With the updates to the one that I had previously said was really slow, it turns out to be the simplest and just about as fast and not use any more memory.  Also, if this answers your question, I'd appreciate you selecting it as the accepted answer with the big checkmark :)